# How to get element coordinate system information (location, angle) for each element using ANSYS Mechanical APDL

Tags: ansys, ansys-workbench, ansys-apdl

We can get local coordinate system information (location and rotation angle (in degrees) relative to the global Cartesian coordinate system.) by using `*GET, Par, CDSY, N, LOC, X (Y or Z)` or `*GET, Par, CDSY, N, ANG, XY (YZ or ZX)`.

Is there a way to get the element coordinate system information for each element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like any other `*get` function you can use in APDL, you can loop on each element (or on each element of a group) and fill an array:

```
allsel
*get,nbe,elem,all,count
wanted_SYS= 11
*del,myarray
*dim,myarray,array,nbe,6
*do,i,1,nbe,1
    esel,s,,,i
    *get,myarray(i,1),cdsy,wanted_SYS,loc,x
    *get,myarray(i,2),cdsy,wanted_SYS,loc,y
    *get,myarray(i,3),cdsy,wanted_SYS,loc,z
    *get,myarray(i,4),cdsy,wanted_SYS,ang,xy
    *get,myarray(i,5),cdsy,wanted_SYS,ang,yz
    *get,myarray(i,6),cdsy,wanted_SYS,ang,zx
*enddo
```